# ComboBox Render in DotNetBar SuperDataGrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, combobox, render, dotnetbar

I want to render a column in the DotNetBar SuperDataGrid Controll as a comboBox (more precisely as a `GridComboBoxExEditControl`) .
The `SuperDataGrid` is connected to a binding source.
In the `DataBindingComplete` Event I have the following:

```
Private Sub SuperGrid_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevComponents.DotNetBar.SuperGrid.GridDataBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles SuperGrid.DataBindingComplete
    Dim panel As DevComponents.DotNetBar.SuperGrid.GridPanel
    panel = e.GridPanel

    panel.Columns("ArticleID").RenderType = GetType(MyComboBox)
    panel.Columns("ArticleID").RenderParams = New Object() {ArticleBindingSource, "Article", "Article"}

End Sub
```

And the MyComboBox class goes:

```
Public Class MyComboBox
Inherits GridComboBoxExEditControl
Public Sub New(ByVal Bind As BindingSource, ByVal disp As String, ByVal val As String)
    DataSource = Bind
    DisplayMember = disp
    ValueMember = val
End Sub
End Class
```

This results in the the following:
The SuperDataGrid Shows the correct Values in the cells. The binding is correct and every value of "ArticleID" if rendered as "Article". 
The problem is that when the value shifts From `ArticleID = 1 to ArticleID = 2` 
(Article = "Article No1" to Article = "Artcle No2") the SuperDataGrid goes in some form of endless loop and the value start shifting between 1 and 2. Am I doing something wrong?
If anyone can offer some advice on this subject I will be very grateful.
P.S. 
I also tried this:

```
panel.Columns("ArticleID").EditorType = GetType(GridComboBoxExEditControl)
Dim art As GridComboBoxExEditControl = DirectCast(panel.Columns("ArticleID").EditControl, GridComboBoxExEditControl)
        art.DataSource = ArticleBindingSource
        art.DisplayMember = "Article"
art.ValueMember = "ArticleID"
```

Got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

{ArticleBindingSource, "Article", "ArticleID"} I think incorect when same value for DisplayMember,
    ValueMember